# Problems installing tensorflow 1.10.0 after the release of tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, virtualenv

I'm using a virtual environment (venv) trying to do an installation of tensorflow 1.10.0 with pip version 22.1.2 and python 3.8.1; however, after running pip install tensorflow==1.10.0, there is no version below tensorflow 2.2. Is there any way to install this? Or should I downgrade python/pip?

Thanks!

Comment: you can: (1) downgrate Python, (2) download source code for 1.10.0 and compile it for Python 3.8 on your system - see [Build from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source?hl=en), (3) check on GitHub in [aroslavvb/tensorflow-community-wheels](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow-community-wheels/issues) - maybe someone already compiled this version for  your system

Comment: @furas why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @FlyingTeller I started write it as short comment and meanwhile I decide to search links with details. But maybe you are right and I should put it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what system you use. I have experience only with Linux.

You can:

1. downgrate Python or rather install older version as second Python. It needs version `3.6`. On Linux you can have many versions at the same time and run as `python3.6`, `python3.8` and the same `pip3.6`, `pip3.8`
2. download source code for 1.10.0 and compile it for Python 3.8 on your system - see [Build from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source?hl=en).
   It needs to install `C/C++ compiler` and `Bazel` to run compilation. Compilation may take few hours. Few years ago I compiled version 1.14 for my CPU without AVX and it took ~8 hour. [furas / tensorflow-no-avx](https://github.com/furas/tensorflow-no-avx)
3. check on GitHub in [aroslavvb / tensorflow-community-wheels](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow-community-wheels/issues)- maybe someone already compiled this version for your system. Sometimes you may find some precompiled version in other repos on GitHub.